# ckeditor5 removes video tags from content

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have added the content of a post to the database.

```
   <div style="width: 1920px;" class="wp-video">
      <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-0-8" width="1920" height="1080" preload="metadata" controls="controls">
         <source type="video/mp4" src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Lowerthird_2_73.mp4?_=8">
         <a href="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Lowerthird_2_73.mp4">https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Lowerthird_2_73.mp4</a>
      </video>
   </div>
```

And when I open the content of this post with `ckeditor5`, it converts the above `html` as follows:

```
<p>
   <a href="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Lowerthird_2_73.mp4" class="ck-link_selected">https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Lowerthird_2_73.mp4</a>
</p>
```

My codes are as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="document-editor editor">
     <div class="document-editor__toolbar"></div>
     <div class="document-editor__editable-container">
          <div class="document-editor__editable">
             {!!$product->description!!}
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
    let editor;

   DecoupledDocumentEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '.document-editor__editable' ), {
                extraPlugins: [ MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ],
                placeholder: "Description",
                mediaEmbed: {
                    extraProviders: [
                        {
                            name: 'allow-all',
                            url: /^.+/,
                            html: match => embededMedia
                        },
                    ]
                },      
            } )
            .then( newEditor => {
                editor = newEditor;
        
                // Set a custom container for the toolbar.
                document.querySelector( '.document-editor__toolbar' ).appendChild( editor.ui.view.toolbar.element );
                document.querySelector( '.ck-toolbar' ).classList.add( 'ck-reset_all' );
            } )
            .catch( error => {
            } );
```

I also used `Laravel8` on the server side.

How can ckeditor be prevented from doing this peacefully?

Comment: ckeditor has configuration options. By default these are set up to only allow certain common, non-problem tags. You can start your research into how to configure this with: [Why does the editor filter out my content (styles, classes, elements)? Where is `config.allowedContent = true`?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#why-does-the-editor-filter-out-my-content-styles-classes-elements-where-is-configallowedcontent-true)